# Find an interval such that the intersection has measure $\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $E$ is measurable with finite lebesgue measure. Show that for each $0<\epsilon<m(E)$, there exists $x>0$ such that $m(E\cap (-x,x))=\epsilon$

I tried to use the $m(E)=\inf\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}l(I_k): \{I_k\}$ is a cover of open intervals of $E\}$, but this would only give me the estimation. I can rewrite $E$ as a disjoint union of a finite number of measurable sets each of which has measure at most $\epsilon$.

Now define $g(x)=m(E_x)$, $E_x=E\cap (-x,x)$, I know that $g$ is non-decreasing, so $g$ is differentiable almost everywhere. But when I calculate the derivative of $g$, I start from the definition, $$g'(x)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$$
I have no idea how to deal with the parts $E\cap(-x-h,-x)$ and $E\cap(x,x+h)$

Comment: sorry, it should be $m(E\cap (-x,x))=\epsilon$.

Comment: Can you show that $g$ is continuous?

Comment: @XanderHenderson, I know how to show g is continuous, that solves the first problem, but I am still trying to find the derivative of g.

Comment: Your goal is to show that you can find some $x$ such that $g(x) = \varepsilon$, yes?  If $g$ is continuous, then you may invoke the intermediate value theorem, and you are done.  Why do you want to compute the derivative?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, that is the question 2, compute $g'(x)$ wherever it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** If $0<x <y$ then $g(x) \leq g(y)$ and

$$g(y)-g(x) \leq 2(y-x)$$

Use this to show that $g$ is continuous.

Comment: thank you, this immediately gives the continuity of $g$. But how do we compute the derivative of g?

Comment: @user335468 Why do you need the derivative? You know that $g(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) =\mu(E) >\epsilon$ thus you can apply intermediate value property.

Comment: sorry about the confusion, that is the second question, find $g'(x)$ wherever it exists.

Comment: @user335468 I think that it is easy to find $g'(x)$ if $x$ is an interiour or exteriour point of $E$, but I am not sure what happens on the boundary...