# Show that for each $0\leq \epsilon < m(E)$, there exists $x\geq0$ such that $m(E\cap [-x,x])=\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Following up on this post [Find an interval such that the intersection has measure $\epsilon$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380527/find-an-interval-such-that-the-intersection-has-measure-epsilon) I was trying to show that given $E$ a Lebesgue-measurable set with finite measure, then for every $0\leq \epsilon < m(E)$, there exists $x \geq 0$ such that $m(E\cap [-x,x])=\epsilon$.

Based on a suggestion from that post I've been able to prove that $g(x) = m(E \cap [-x,x])$ is Lipschitz, hence continuous. I would like now to conclude that $Im(g) \supseteq [0, m(E)]$. If I am able to show this, as $g$ is continuous then for every $\epsilon \in [0,m(E)], \ \exists x \geq 0: g(x) = \epsilon$.

If $x = 0$, then $g(x) = m(E \cap \{0\}) = 0$. Now If $x$ goes to infinity then $[-x,x] \to \mathbb{R}$. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}m(E \cap [-x,x]) = m(lim_{x\to\infty}E \cap [-x,x]) = m(E \cap \mathbb{R}) = m(E)$ then I think we can conclude that $Im(g) \supseteq [0,m(E)]$. But I don't know if I can take the limit from outside the measure into it. Can I do this? If so, why?

Comment: Shouldn't you be proving the other direction of inclusion? If $Im(g) \subseteq [0,m(E)]$ then this just says that $g(x) \in [0,m(e)]$ it doesn't say that for any $\epsilon \in [0,m(E)]$ there is some x so that $g(x) = \epsilon$. For this you need to prove that $[0,m(E)] \subseteq Im(g)$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's what I intended to prove. I've made the edit.

Answer (score 1):

$[-x,x]\to \Bbb{R}$ sure does sound intuitive, but what you really need is a basic form of “monotone convergence”: for any measure space $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$,  if $A_1\subset A_2\subset\dots$ is a sequence of measurable sets and $A=\bigcup A_n$ their union, then
\begin{align}
\mu(A)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)=\sup\limits_{n\geq 1}\mu(A_n).
\end{align}
This is called continuity from below. To prove this, let $B_1=A_1$, and for $n\geq 2$, $B_n=A_n\setminus A_{n-1}$. Then, the $B$’s are pairwise disjoint, and $A_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k$ and $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k$. Use countable additivity of measures and the definition of a series.

---

**Edit:**

Now that I think about the question further, the question is false as stated. It should be $0\leq \epsilon< m(E)$. The strict inequality is important in order for you to apply the intermediate-value theorem. We have  $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}g(x)=m(E)$ and $g$ is an (weakly-)increasing function on $[0,\infty)$, so given $0\leq\epsilon<m(E)$, we can find some $R>0$ large enough such that for all $x\geq R$, we have $g(x)\in (\epsilon,m(E))$. Now we can apply the intermediate-value theorem on $[0,R]$.

To see that we have to exclude $\epsilon=m(E)$, consider a set $E$ of finite measure but “going off to infinity while carrying positive mass”. For example, let $E$ be the union of sets $E_n=\left(n,n+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$ so that $E_n$ has measure $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and they are all disjoint. Then, $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ has finite measure, but for every $x\geq 0$, $E\cap [-x,x]$ has strictly smaller measure than $E$.

If on the other hand, you restrict $E$ to be bounded, then you can go all the way up to $\epsilon=m(E)$.

And finally a fun variant for you to think about: given $\epsilon\in (0,1)$, construct a set $E\subset [0,1]$ such that $E$ is dense and $m(E)=\epsilon$.

Comment: So going back to my problem. If I define $A_n = [-n,n]$, then $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$. Can I state then that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n \cap E) = \mu(E \cap \bigcup A_n) = \mu(E \cap \mathbb{R}) = \mu(E)$ by the continuity from below property?

Comment: @SaimFaigol what is $L$? Anyway, just apply the theorem correctly with a careful choice of $A_n$. If you want to apply the theorem, just check that its assumption (there is only one) is satisfied. This is very straightforward (and if you don’t think it’s straightforward, spend some time thinking until it is :).

Comment: Sorry, I used a wrong notation, what about now?